# Why does .NET Regex return different results with alternation?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-alternation

I tested this piece of code in .NET Framework 4.7.2:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Regex r;

        r = new Regex("^\\.vs$");
        ShowMatch(r, ".vs");
        ShowMatch(r, ".vsa");
        ShowMatch(r, "avs");
        ShowMatch(r, "c.vs");
        
        Console.WriteLine();

        r = new Regex("^bin|obj|\\.vs$");
        ShowMatch(r, "bin");
        ShowMatch(r, "s.bin");
        ShowMatch(r, "obj");
        ShowMatch(r, ".vs");
        ShowMatch(r, ".vsa");
        ShowMatch(r, "avs");
        ShowMatch(r, "c.vs");
    }
    
    public static void ShowMatch(Regex r, string input)
    {
        bool b = r.IsMatch(input);
        Console.WriteLine("Pattern: {0}  Input: {1,-10}  IsMatch: {2}", r, input, b);
    }
}
```

I got this output:

```
Pattern: ^\.vs$  Input: .vs         IsMatch: True
Pattern: ^\.vs$  Input: .vsa        IsMatch: False
Pattern: ^\.vs$  Input: avs         IsMatch: False
Pattern: ^\.vs$  Input: c.vs        IsMatch: False

Pattern: ^bin|obj|\.vs$  Input: bin         IsMatch: True
Pattern: ^bin|obj|\.vs$  Input: s.bin       IsMatch: False
Pattern: ^bin|obj|\.vs$  Input: obj         IsMatch: True
Pattern: ^bin|obj|\.vs$  Input: .vs         IsMatch: True
Pattern: ^bin|obj|\.vs$  Input: .vsa        IsMatch: False
Pattern: ^bin|obj|\.vs$  Input: avs         IsMatch: False
Pattern: ^bin|obj|\.vs$  Input: c.vs        IsMatch: True
```

I don't understand why "c.vs" with the alternation pattern (^bin|obj|.vs$) *is* considered as a match while the same input with the simple pattern (^.vs$) is not (expected behavior).

Comment: Because the `^` anchor only applies to `bin`, and the `$` anchor only applies to `\.vs`. You need `^(?:bin|obj|\.vs)$`

Comment: My guess is that the ^ and $ characters bind "stronger" in the pattern than the alternation character (|). But I don't know.

Comment: That is correct. See the explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/qhlFzz/1)

Comment: Thanks @Nick, I was not sure. Spent a couple of hours of investigating.

Comment: @Nick You should post your comments as answer.

Comment: @Orifjon I've already vtc'd as a dupe (so it would be inappropriate to answer too), and I'm pretty sure there's a better dupe out there somewhere, I just couldn't find it.

Comment: @Nick My experience is there are different "flavors" of regex processing on different platforms / in different languages. At the first glance, I would probably not look at MySQL related questions since I'm working in .NET, C#. But generally speaking, the question with MySQL stuff answers what I had been looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @PavelFoltyn absolutely; that's why I said there's almost certainly a better dupe somewhere (e.g. specific to .NET). However the alternation priority rule is constant; if you change the regex flavour on that demo I linked they all show the `^` linked with `bin` and the `$` linked with `\.vs`

Comment: @Nick Actually, I didn't know about regex101. Thanks for pointing me there.

Comment: It's a great site. Really good for playing with your regexes before you commit them to code.